# how to install htmldoc on wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp, htmldoc

I want to install htmldoc on wamp. My environnment is apache 2.2, php5.3, windows XP.
I followed the instructions on htmldoc website but it does not work, I think I missed something that is obvious and therefore not said in the doc.

I followed these instructions : http://www.easysw.com/htmldoc/docfiles/5-cgi.html#6_3_3

That's what I did : downloaded htmldoc executable (msi) and installed it in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\cgi-bin. As I'm on windows, I don't think I can do symlink so I put it directly here. I executed htmldoc.exe, which opened briefly a windows and closed it (I supposed it wrote the keys in the registry).

Then I opened httpd.conf and added AcceptPathInfo On anywhere (actually just after LoadModule part). I'm quite sure it's not necessary, but I added AddHandler cgi-script .cgi too, and in my alias, I added Options +ExecCGI.

Then I restarted Wamp.

When I execute my php code, the pdf is created but it is empty. I had the same thing before I tried to install htmldoc.

I'm quite sure the php code works because it works on another (linux) server.

Is there something I have to install ? (cgi, pear maybe ?) Has anyone found a solution to this problem ?

Thank you for your help,

Mariek

EDIT : 
the command used is :

```
system("exec htmldoc -t pdf --quiet --webpage $options '$filename' > pdf/myfile.pdf");
header("Location: pdf/myfile.pdf");
```

and Apache error log shows :
    exec is not recognized as an intern command...

In my path environment I have C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5;C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\cgi-bin\;

Comment: FYI, I never made it work, I finally worked on linux